# MVC3 View Routing and partial view not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know what my problem is but not sure how to fix it so I was hoping the geniuses here could help. I have a controller that I want to grab a piece of info from the url then redirect to the site. My controller does it's thing and returns the view but the view has a partial in it and the view engine can't find it?

So here is the setup.

The controller is mapped route as:

```
//marketing/tracking
routes.MapRoute("CampaignTracking",
                "{save}/{campaignid}",
        new { controller = "CampaignTracking", action = "Index" });
```

This works great. So next my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(Int32 campaignID)
{
        var model = new ...snip...

        return View("../Customer/Login", model);
}
```

Now I originally got the error couldn't find view as it was looking in a CampaignTracking folder and I had :

```
return View("Customer/Login", model);
```

So I changed it as seen above with the ../ to get to the correct location. Now it finds the Login.cshtml but in login.cshtml it renders a partial and again it is looking to find the partial in the Campaigntracking.

I could abolish the CampaignTracking controller and move the action result into the CustomerController but would prefer to keep it in its own controller as this will likely grow and doesn't really group under customer.

> As per nicu Janga

I changed in my controller:

```
return View(@"~/Views/Customer/Login.cshtml", model);
```

and in my login.cshtml the partials:

```
@Html.Partial(@"~/Views/Customer/...etc.cshtml")
```

but I am wondering why. I can understand how the view engine gets confused coming out of the controller but once corrected with return View(@"~/Views/Customer/Login.cshtml", model); shouldn't the proper path propagate as well to the login.cshtml???

Obviously not but what don't I understand??

Comment: You need to use the `~` tilde character to specify the URL relative to the site root, rather than relative to the current controller/page. Try `View("~/Customer/Login")` instead (assuming the view is at http://yoursiteroot/Customer/Login.cshtml

Comment: You can put the view file in the "Shared" directory and not worry about the full path. Just `return View("Login", model);`

Comment: @Charleh it doesn't like the syntax...The following locations were searched:
~/Customer/Login

Comment: @DigitalD Would moving it break the controller references to it or would they also search the shared directory without me refactoring?

Comment: The default conventions say search the shared directory for the view - the server error you get shows you the locations it looked for the view

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one:

```
   return View(@"~/Views/Customer/Login.cshtml",model);
```

it works?

Comment: That takes me back to the original post. It finds the Login.cshtml but the html.partial in Login.cshtml is not found.

Comment: because mvc is using something like I call harcode . View must be in folder  with same name as controller.you can move you partial to shared folder ,but again will be nut so nice.

Comment: So to get around it means making my own view engine? Should I then refactor everything to partial(@"...") or View(@"...")???

Comment: @user1278561 You don't need the `@` there.  That's only used when you want to treat a string as a literal (meaning you don't have to use escape sequences).  That's not needed here.  The important part is the `~/`, because that indicates the root of the site.

Comment: You must! this will improve the  view rendering for all your project.

Comment: @nicuJanga No it doesn't: [2.4.4.5 String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: ~/Views/Customer/Login.cshtml --> this will improve..I dont't care about "@"

Comment: Well maybe I am doing something wrong but performance aside if I don't use the @ string literal character it doesn't work at all. See my response to Charleh. Again MVC 3 razor engine if that matters to this debate.

Comment: @user1278561 It's not the `@`, it's `~/Views/...`.  I'm writing an answer now to explain it all.

Answer (score 2):

Let me see if I can fill in some details for you.  First up, let's say we've just added the following controller to an empty project:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now, let's also assume that we didn't bother to add the `Index.cshtml` view, so when we run this, it will tell us the view is missing.  Take a look at the message that accompanies that exception:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports
the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/home/Index.aspx
~/Views/home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

These are the exact locations that are searched when MVC is trying to locate a view.  For the most part, if you're using C# with MVC, the only two you need to care about are:

```
~/Views/home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

That means if you don't provide a path when specifying the name of your view, it will always check both of these locations.  So if we did this from our `HomeController`:

```
return View("Test");
```

MVC will look for this view at `~/Views/Home/Test.cshtml` and then `~/Views/Shared/Test.cshtml`.  The great thing about this is it's *consistent*.  It always looks for the views in the same way.

Now, let's use a more complicated example (again, assuming we're in our `HomeController`):

```
return View("../SomeDirectory/Test.cshtml");
```

This is going to be looked for in the following ways:

```
~/Views/Home/../SomeDirectory/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/../SomeDirectory/Index.cshtml
```

Taking a look at `~/Views/Home/../SomeDirectory/Index.cshtml` first , this would actually mean it's searching for the view here: `~/Views/SomeDirectory/Index.cshtml`.  Obviously, this isn't where your view is, and the same applies to where `~/Views/Shared/../SomeDirectory/Index.cshtml` ends up.

The important thing to remember here is `~` means the relative root of your site.  It will always work from the root of your site, which means you can always be sure exactly what's going on.  By doing this

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

you are telling MVC *exactly where to find your view*, rather than letting MVC's rules of convention decide for you.  That means whenever you specify a location for MVC to find your view, it will **only** search that location.  So  `return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")` will **only** search for the view at `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`.  If it cannot find the view there, you'll get the same exception as before, but it will give you a slightly different message:

```
The view '~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' or its master was not found or no view
engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

Notice how it hasn't searched for the view in the other locations.

Comment: It works this way as well. I must have typod something when I tried it as charlieh originally suggested.

Comment: @user1278561 Judging by your earlier comment, you did.  You said this: `it doesn't like the syntax...The following locations were searched: ~/Customer/Login` so it looks like you just missed off the `/Views/` part.

Comment: so the remaining curiosity is how the partials inside the cshtml also need the path switched to a relative path notation. Somehow the context of the controller must stick around even for the partials that are in the same namespace aka folder as the cshtml calling them.

Comment: @user1278561 That's why you either don't specify a path, or you specify a path starting from `~/Views/`.  This is what I was talking about when I mentioned consistency.  This way guarantees your views will be located correctly.  Specifying anything other than a root-relative path (e.g. `../SomeFolder/`) is going to cause problems.  The consistent approaches prevent that.