# Controller with different location to view form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a need to use a controller for a form but in a different location.
I have a registration form which is a CMS page hosted in the database. It was using AJAX to register a user but I would prefer it to use POST like the default register form because I want to use the validation summary.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "_Account", new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "register", @novalidate = "novalidate", role = "form" }))
```

although the page is served up on **/Account/Register**. Is there anyway to make it return the View() to my page from **/_Account/Register** ??

Cheers

Comment: create _AccountController class. But not sure, asp.net will allow you to access the resource name starts with `_` directly

Comment: try to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966334/mvc3-view-routing-and-partial-view-not-found/19966645#19966645